# How to update the rows using dynamic table in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, snowflake-stage

I had created one source table,it has two columns (ID,NAME) ID is the primary key. And I have created dynamic table (names) which works for insert and delete operation but update operation is not working. I need help to solve this issue. Can someone provide solution for how to update the rows in dynamic table?

**source table**

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | nick |
| 1 | nick |
| 2 | john |
| 2 | john |
| 2 | michel |

**Dynamic Table**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DYNAMIC TABLE names
TARGET_LAG = '1 minute'
WAREHOUSE = "COM_WH"
SELECT ID,NAME,current_timestamp() FROM SOURCE_TABLE;
```

**names**

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | nick |
| 1 | nick |
| 2 | john |
| 2 | john |
| 2 | michel |

**Expecting Result from dynamic table:**

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | nick |
| 2 | michel |

But i'm getting duplicate records in dynamic table.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/dynamic-tables-about

In the above link they gave example for task and stream replace with   dynamic table

In task i can do update if the id's are same but dynamic table i cant do update

Comment: Your source table and dynamic table seem to be identical - which is what is expected. What are you expecting to see? Can you update your question to show what updates you are making?

Comment: A dynamic table will contain the results of the query you specify. Your query will return all records in SOURCE_TABLE - which is what you are seeing in your dynamic table. So it's all working as I would expect

Comment: FYI the tags I took off your question and which you've now put back on are irrelevant to your question. SNOWFLAKE-SCHEMA: this refers to a data modelling artifact/methodology and has nothing to do with Snowflake the database. SNOWFLAKE-STAGE: your question has nothing to do with Snowflake Stages so I'm not sure why you are using this tag?

Comment: could you refer this link https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/dynamic-tables-about,in this link they mentioned dynamic table is the replacement of task and stream and they provided one example. In that example they mentioned select statement only will work in dynamic table.
In task,we can do insert,delete and update based on the specific condition.In dynamic table we cant write update query.so,how the update operation will works in dynamic table.

Comment: To quote the documentation, “A dynamic table materializes the results of a query that you specify” - I’m not sure what else I can tell you. You need to specify a query that results in the dataset you want to see in your dynamic table

Comment: Dynamic tables are like materialized views in other RDBMS solutions.  You create one against your source table(s) to create a final table.  Most Snowflake users today are using tasks/streams to update a final target based on incremental changes from source table(s).  So, Dynamic tables replaces that use-case.  You shouldn't need to update the dynamic table directly, as the data that is changing in the underlying source tables will automatically be reflected in the final dynamic table target.

Comment: I should also point out that using `current_timestamp()` in your select for dynamic table will end up rebuilding your entire dynamic table (in your example case, every minute).  You don't want to do that.

Comment: Also bear in mind that this Feature is in Public Preview and there are changes/bug fixes still being released for it - so probably not wise to use them in a Production environment until they go GA

Comment: Based on your update to your question, I think you're just missing a `DISTINCT` in your select statement.